# Prove integral inequality for divergence-free vector fields

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $u$ be a divergence-free vector field $u:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^ n$. Does the following inequality hold?

$$\Big( \int_{\mathbb R^n} |u|^2 dx\Big)^2 \le C\Big(\int_{\mathbb R^n} |u|^2|x|^2 dx \Big) \Big(\int_{\mathbb R^n}  |\nabla u|^2 dx \Big). $$

How can it be proved? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: The inequality does not seem to scale well for functions $A\cdot u$ and $A\to 0$.

Comment: @Dirk Sorry for the typo: I wrote two extra exponents

Comment: Looks pretty much like the Heisenberg uncertainty principle for the Fourier transform to me. Am I missing some subtlety here?